# Not able to start Docker after Windows 10 system restart

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

Docker runs fine after the installation. But it stopped working after my system restart.

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Docker Version: 3.1.0

Things i have tried so far:

- Restarting Docker Desktop Service
- Reinstalling Docker
- Removing Oracle VM
- Following steps mention in https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-uninstall-docker-for-windows/15661/11
- Running it as Administrator
- Removing from Hyper-V and starting it again but again failed

Here is the log.txt-

```
> Version: 3.1.0 (51484)
Sha1: 04f280b1648e29845ae5734cfcc14796c92f3de2
Started on: 2021/03/18 09:45:36.766
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 1903
Build: 18362
BuildLabName: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
File: C:\Users\anukumar0\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" 
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[09:45:36.873][GUI               ][Info   ] Starting...
[09:45:36.888][ComponentVersions ][Info   ] Edition community
[09:45:36.904][ComponentVersions ][Info   ] Edition community
[09:45:36.957][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [6067c7db] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:36.989][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:37.142][AppMigrator       ][Info   ] Current version: 6. Latest version: 6
[09:45:37.177][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Starting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe -addr unix:\\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer
[09:45:37.301][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [01b56c61] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:37.304][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:37.459][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Started
[09:45:37.461][TrackingSettings  ][Info   ] Crash report and usage statistics are enabled
[09:45:37.464][SegmentApi        ][Info   ] Usage statistic: Identify
[09:45:37.607][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [cd6fa0c3] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:38.423][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:38.743][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [7c2aea06] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:38.743][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:39.060][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ceb88dcc] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:39.060][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:39.376][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [5135b03d] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:39.376][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:39.693][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [f36ac4e8] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:39.693][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:39.994][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [d068fb95] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:39.994][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:40.310][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [d4d18e29] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:40.310][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:40.610][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [fb06add0] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:40.610][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:40.911][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [6ed2e1c8] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:40.911][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:41.228][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [0f328351] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:41.228][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:41.529][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [4f3f672f] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:41.529][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:41.852][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ef65ea07] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:41.852][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:42.161][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [eec915e8] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:42.161][GoBackendClient   ][Warning] HttpOS Client: connection timed out.
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] ⇨ http server started on \\.\pipe\dockerVpnKitControl
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="starting backend server"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="started port-forwarding control server on \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerVpnKitControl"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] ⇨ http server started on \\.\pipe\docker_cli
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Error  ] msg="unable to query WslEngineEnabled state after 0s. Last error was Get \"http://unix/settings\": open \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerWebApiServer: The system cannot find the file specified."
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] ⇨ http server started on \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="listening on unix:\\\\.\\pipe\\dockerVpnkitData for data connection"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] ⇨ http server started on \\.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServerForGuest
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /docker.tar"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /kube-images.tar"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /services.tar -> C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\services.tar"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /docker.tar"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /kube-images.tar"
[09:45:42.406][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="adding routes for /services.tar -> C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\services.tar"
[09:45:42.463][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [3bffb9fe] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/ping
[09:45:42.478][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /ping 200 \"DockerDesktopCSharp\" \"\""
[09:45:42.503][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [3bffb9fe] <GoBackendClient end> GET http://localhost/ping -> 200 OK (took 39ms)
[09:45:42.514][GoBackendClient   ][Info   ] backend API ready
[09:45:42.514][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [0cb7fb92] <GoBackendClient start> GET http://localhost/features
[09:45:42.515][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: GET /features 200 \"DockerDesktopCSharp\" \"\""
[09:45:42.518][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [0cb7fb92] <GoBackendClient end> GET http://localhost/features -> 200 OK (took 3ms)
[09:45:42.615][SegmentApi        ][Info   ] Usage statistic: appLaunched
[09:45:42.626][SegmentApi        ][Info   ] Usage statistic: heartbeat
[09:45:43.886][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [425f8b28] <Server start> GET http://unix/settings
[09:45:44.002][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [425f8b28] <Server end> GET http://unix/settings -> 200 OK (took 115ms)
[09:45:44.067][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="NewSharer: grpcfuse feature enabled"
[09:45:44.067][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="enabling filesystem caching"
[09:45:44.068][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="filesystem exports are:  (2)"
[09:45:44.068][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="volume control server listening on \\\\.\\pipe\\dockerVolume"
[09:45:44.070][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="filesystem server listening on 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:00001003-facb-11e6-bd58-64006a7986d3"
[09:45:44.070][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="file ownership will be determined by the calling user (\"fake owner\" mode)"
[09:45:44.070][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="using mfsymlinks"
[09:45:46.390][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [46fa5bed] <BackendAPIClient start> GET http://backend/version
[09:45:46.413][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [46fa5bed] <BackendAPIClient end> GET http://backend/version -> 200 OK (took 8ms)
[09:45:46.475][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [4092ebf3] <BackendAPIClient start> GET http://backend/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx
[09:45:46.769][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [4092ebf3] <BackendAPIClient end> GET http://backend/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx -> 200 OK (took 292ms)
[09:45:46.785][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [bd3ae380] <BackendAPIClient start> POST http://backend/migrate/app
[09:45:46.785][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [bd3ae380] <BackendAPIClient end> POST http://backend/migrate/app -> 204 NoContent (took 4ms)
[09:45:50.852][DockerHub         ][Info   ] Login successfull
[09:45:50.857][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [b780604e] <GoBackendClient start> POST http://localhost/hub-login
[09:45:52.773][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="user is part of free plan"
[09:45:52.773][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="entitlement: {PlanName:free Desktop:{Enabled:false}}"
[09:45:52.773][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] msg="external: POST /hub-login 200 \"DockerDesktopCSharp\" \"\""
[09:45:52.774][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [b780604e] <GoBackendClient end> POST http://localhost/hub-login -> 200 OK (took 1916ms)
[09:45:52.847][Updater           ][Info   ] Launcher process exited with 4294967289
[09:45:55.211][Updater           ][Info   ] Launcher process exited with 4294967295
[09:45:55.226][Diagnostics       ][Info   ] Diagnostics cancelled by user
[09:45:55.226][Diagnostics       ][Info   ] Diagnostics cancelled by user
[09:45:55.226][Engines           ][Debug  ] Stopping
```

Can someone please help me here. i am trying to figure it out form last 3-4 days.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried Trobleshoot => Reset to factory defaults ?